# findpeaks - a function in Python to find peaks in data with irregular x-grid, providing

Tags: python, signal-processing, detection

I am using a scipy.signal.findpeaks to find peaks coordinates and characteristics (such as peaks widths, prominences, etc..)

```
Yi = f(Xi)
```

where "i" stands for the point number in a dataset (current signal curve).
Xi - is the x coordinate for the signal
Yi - is the value of a signal at Xi

When I had a regular x-grid - this package and function worked perfectly - for the cases where x(i)-x(i-1) = const, and there was the ability just to recalculate the possible width from real x values to sample counts.

but when I started to work with signals with irregular grids (nonuniform, so the distance between nearest points varies)

```
x(i)-x(i-1)<>x(i+1)-x(i)
```

it just gives me bad results.

I have used the package with the parameter width - which required knowing the min or max peak width (in samples).

```
all_peaks_indexes = signal.find_peaks(signal_y, prominence = search_peak_prominence, width=1, height=1)
```

Unfortunately, parameter width has a dimension of sample count in a signal that is very convenient if you have signal data with an irregular grid along the x-axis...

```
**WIDTH** - Required width of peaks in samples. 
Either a number, None, an array matching x, or a 2-element sequence of the former. 
The first element is always interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied, as
the maximal required width.
```

The point is that find_peaks doesn't know anything about the actual values of X coordinates - it just uses indexes (sample numbers) instead of X values.
And the actual width can't be used in this case.

Maybe there is some package/library that provides a similar functionality - peak detection and parametrization but with the possibility to search peaks using widths and dimensions of the input signal (e.g. time), irregular x-grid..?

Or maybe you can suggest an approach to deal with that problem...

Answer (score 0):

i wrote an algorithm in java that may help you.
The algorithm i propose have the parameter delta that gives some flexibility while detecting peaks but you can modify the solution and add some logic to cover your needs :)

https://github.com/b-elamine/Peaks-detection-algorithm

This algorithm is a solution for the problem of finding local maxima and minima in noisy signals. The well known Zero-derivate methode may not work well because of the noise in the signal so it will detect some meaningless peaks. With the zero-derivate method you have to apply a low-pass filter to the signal in purpose of getting rid of the noise but this will kill somehow the original signal and give usually horrible results. So in this algorithm we didn't think about the problem in a mathematical way, the logique is simple to detect a peak we just need to detect a lower points around it in both sides of the x axis.

This is the python version of the code

```
#peaks detection function

import sys
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, asarray, array
def peakdet(v, delta, x = None):
    maxtab = []
    mintab = []
    if x is None:
        x = arange(len(v))
    v = asarray(v)
    if len(v) != len(x):
        sys.exit('Input vectors v and x must have same length')
    if not isscalar(delta):
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be a scalar')
    if delta <= 0:
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be positive')
    mn, mx = Inf, -Inf
    mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN
    lookformax = True
    for i in arange(len(v)):
        this = v[i]
        if this > mx:
            mx = this
            mxpos = x[i]
        if this < mn:
            mn = this
            mnpos = x[i]
        if lookformax:
            if this < mx-delta:
                maxtab.append((mxpos, mx))
                mn = this
                mnpos = x[i]
                lookformax = False
        else:
            if this > mn+delta:
                mintab.append((mnpos, mn))
                mx = this
                mxpos = x[i]
                lookformax = True
    return array(maxtab) #or mintab or both in an array :)
```

I tried both scipy.signal.findpeaks and i'm still using the algorithm above it is giving me accurate and flexible results :)

Comment: Please not post images of the source code. It is hard to interpret and adopt.

Comment: @AzharKhan i did edit the post you can now interpret or adopt the code as you want hope this is useful :)